# Model#id returns #object_id in haml views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, decorator

I'm having a weird error in my haml views. When I ask for `model.id` it returns `object_id` but only in some places. Example:

```
%ul
  - @items.each do |item|
    %li{:class => "item", :id => "item_#{item.id}"}= link_to(item.name,item)
```

The code above renders this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="item" id="item_104589"><a href="/items/1">Test1</a></li>
  <li class="item" id="item_104590"><a href="/items/2">Test2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I said this is a weird error because it's only happening on production environment and links are correct.
The array of items are "decorated" using [Drapper](https://github.com/esdras/draper) gem. I'm not using the short form of haml because of this:

```
%li[item]
```

Renders:

```
<li class="item_decorator" id="item_decorator_xxx">...</li>
```

Comment: Using item[:id] instead of item.id solved my problem. More weirdness :/

Comment: What does `item.class` return inside the view?

Comment: `item.class` returns `ItemDecorator`. Do you think it's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to [Leonid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6678/leonid-shevtsov), I found the problem with `ItemDecorator`.

`ItemDecorator` override the method `id` from class `Item`:

```
item = ItemDecorator.decorate(item)
=> #<ItemDecorator:0xcdbcc78 @context={}, ...
irb(main):004:0> item.id
(irb):4: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
=> 107865660
```

I wonder if it is a bug of [Drapper](https://github.com/esdras/draper) or not.

Comment: It doesn't *override* it, it merely doesn't proxy it to the real `Item`, returning its own object id instead.

Comment: I have install Draper 0.9.3 and it works. They proxy `id` now.

Comment: What was up with that fork anyway?  It seems to have intentionally [*removed*](https://github.com/esdras/draper/blob/master/lib/drapper/base.rb#L8) the `id` proxying... and changed the name of the module to "Drapper"?  What?  Why?  Yeah, using the original codebase is probably a good idea.